# Get reference to event handler assigned to menu item

Tags: android, xamarin

Apparently Android doesn't show text and icon on action menu items in portrait mode. So, I figure I can add an icon as a separate menu item.

If there's already a menu item for the text, how can I make the icon menu item refer to the same event handler? In other words, how can I get reference to the event handler already assigned to the text item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this...

```
imageView.Click += (sender, e) => text.PerformClick();
```